# Updated array, reflect changes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have this bit of code that searches through a user input and then highlights all the uppercase text. I've used a RegExp and splice to do the replace, but I can't seem to figure out how to show the results on screen, only in the console.

```
var allCaps = new RegExp(/(?:[A-Z]{3,30})/g);
var capsArray = [];
var capsFound;
var capitalErrorsList = '';

while (capsFound = allCaps.exec(searchInput)) {
    capsArray.push(capsFound[0]);
}

if(capsArray.length > 0){
    resultsLog.innerHTML += "<p><span class='warning'>Is this an abbreviation? If yes, ensure you have the full version included after its first use.</span></p>";
    for(var five = 0; five < capsArray.length; five++) {
        //display associated text
        capitalErrorsList += '<li>' + capsArray[five] + '</li>';

        capsArray.splice(0, 1, '<span style="background-color: yellow;">'+capsArray[five]+'</span>');

        console.log(capsArray);
    }

    resultsLog.innerHTML += '<ul>' + capitalErrorsList + '</ul>';

}
else {
    resultsLog.innerHTML += "";
}
```

Adding in this bit of code was the closet I got, but it gave some very odd results.

```
searchInput = document.getElementById('findAllErrors').innerHTML;
        searchInput = searchInput.replace(capsArray[five], function(){
            return capsArray.splice(0, 1, '<span style="background-color: yellow;">'+capsArray[five]+'</span>');

        });
```

Comment: In your fiddle, you set `searchInput` (which is what the regex gets executed on) to `document.getElementById('searchInput')`, which is a node, not a string. Try changing that `var searchInput = ...` line to `var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput').innerText` and see if that's a little more successful.

Comment: Also, you can probably neaten up that loop at the end by using `map()`. Let me know if that's what you're trying to do and I'll put an answer together.

Comment: Thanks Ben.

There is an unknown number of capitals in a text area (ex. THIS is ONLY a TEST). For each THIS, ONLY, TEST should be added to an array, the array is looped over and each capitalized letter has a span added to it with a yellow highlight to ask why its been capitalized. I can find the capitalized words, but cannot return the results to the text area.

Comment: I think my answer should fix getting it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/).

If you want to highlight the caps in that input, then you're right in wanting to wrap them in a `<span>`. However, if you went to all the trouble of using regex, how about a regex replace?

```
var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput').innerText;
var replacedText = searchInput.replace(/(?:[A-Z]{3,30})/g, '<span style="background-color: yellow;">$&</span>');
document.getElementById('findAllErrors').innerHTML = replacedText;
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/wznj0uL3/) an updated fiddle for you.

If you're set on your array operations, `map()` creates a new array by applying a function to the input array. So, for your example:

```
var highlighted = capsArray.map(function(caps) {
    return '<span style="background-color: yellow;">' + caps + '</span>';
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. How about using this in a loop? I have a few other things to check for and I wont be able to use the RegExp in the replace.

Comment: What other things do you need to check for? You're probably better off using `map()` on an array than a loop, if it's like this first one.

Comment: Could you give me a map() example? hopefully, i can figure it out.

Comment: My other solution was:

var xMas = new RegExp(capsArray[five], "g");
searchInput = document.getElementById('findAllErrors').innerHTML;
searchInput = searchInput.replace(xMas, '<span style="background-color: yellow;">'+capsArray[five]+'</span>');
document.getElementById('findAllErrors').innerHTML = searchInput;

Which worked, unless there were multiples of the same text (ie TEST, TEST, TEST). Then it added the span 3 times around each TEST.

Comment: Added an example of the map function to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I was stressing over this.

Comment: Does that solve your issue with getting it to the text area though?

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. I thought the return on map() would update the array in the DOM. I tried using replace() that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: You'll need to write the results to a Dom element at some point, that's how it gets to the view. You have to set the innerHTML of findAllErrors if you want to see anything

Comment: Update the fiddle, hopefully, this gives a better idea.  https://jsfiddle.net/ovvrh99y/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156514/discussion-between-ben-and-rw-hammond).